# AVI Decompressor suddenly stopped decoding video with DirectShow Graphedit

Tags: winapi, video, directshow

I have an issue with one of the applications utilizing an AVI Decompressor Filter. The error returns that there is no suitable decompresser that could be found... however it has worked everyday for the past several months. I thought about re-registering quartz.dll however no luck.

I then cracked open Graphedit and found that I could load the filter into the graph but not connect anymore.

Has anybody come across this scenario before? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Cheers.

**EDIT**
If the issue is in the registry, than would a simple system restore do the trick to put the registry back to the way it was. It is too late now to figure out the bug as it happened at a clients end and we had decided to recover windows to get them back up and going. But redundancy checks can be put into place such as automated restore points build into the application to rectify the issue if it ever occurs again. Does anybody think this would work?

Comment: Nobody is following up with the registry idea... but Roman's answer below did show inconsistencies in the registry so I am marking his answer as checked. Cheers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`AVI Decompressor Filter`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd318185%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) is an adapter filter which makes VFW/VCM codecs available to DirectShow. The fact that you can add the filter manually to the graph does not mean it will be useful. This filter typically does not work this way, and in most cases it is added by fitler graph as a part of [Intelligent Connect](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd390342%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

In your case important is the media type you had converted by `AVI Decompressor Filter` to something better suited for further processing or presentation. The media type there might be not the one you expected, or the underlying VCM codec is gone and VI Decompressor cannot pick it up any longer.

In Windows 7, AVI Decompressor uses internally `msyuv.dll`, which is "Microsoft UYVY Video Decompressor". Something is perhaps wrong with it in your system. You might want to check its registration as VFW codec:

```
[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Drivers32]
VIDC.UYVY="msyuv.dll"
```

With 64-bit OS, you might need to look at another key affecting 32-bit apps in 64-bit OS:

```
[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Drivers32]
VIDC.UYVY="msyuv.dll"
```

Comment: The media type has not changed for the past several months. The capture source is a Decklink which works fine under BlackMagic's own software and has always worked fine within the APP itself. It pulls in a source via SDI.

Comment: So what is the media type? If my memory serves me right, Decklink boards - some at least - expose `UYVY` and `HDYC` media types. The first is rendered through VFW codec, through AVI decompressor. The second one - I think it needs an additional codec such as Decklink's to be rendered.

Comment: The media type being used is UYVY and it connects to the AVI Decompressor before rendering to the EVR.

Comment: See above regarding Microsoft UYVY Video Decompressor used internally by AVI Decompressor.

Comment: Will definitely check that... does it make any sense to take another duplicate system, save the registry and load it into the system that is currently failing?

Comment: The VIDC.UYVY was not set to msyuv.dll anymore... it was set to a blackmagic dll... which is very strange, and not sure how this happened. However switching it back did not resolve the issue.

Comment: Alternate decoders might be faster to those from Microsoft, but more often than not they bring up compatibility issues... If you changed that and your OS is 64-bit, then look into `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Drivers32` as well. You might possibly need to reboot to put changes into effect.

Comment: Changed that, rebooted, but still no luck. Ideally... if a restore point was made (in this case there was not)... and we restored from that date where it did work... would that be all thats needed?